# could not connect huawei cloudDb

Tags: flutter, caching, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, clouddb

i try to connect huawei clouddb to my flutter application. i followed huawei developer guide and follow steps correctly but when i run the application i faced this error

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\modules\AGCCloudDBModule.java:29: error: package com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes does not exist
import com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes.ObjectTypeInfoHelper;
                                              ^
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\utils\AGCCloudDBUtil.java:8: error: package com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes does not exist
import com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes.ObjectTypeInfoHelper;
                                              ^
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\modules\AGCCloudDBModule.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
            AGConnectCloudDB.getInstance().createObjectType(ObjectTypeInfoHelper.getObjectTypeInfo());
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable ObjectTypeInfoHelper
  location: class AGCCloudDBModule
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\utils\AGCCloudDBUtil.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        for (Class<? extends CloudDBZoneObject> clazz : ObjectTypeInfoHelper.getObjectTypeInfo().getObjectTypes()) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable ObjectTypeInfoHelper
  location: class AGCCloudDBUtil
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':agconnect_clouddb:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            4.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.